How can multiple std::expected<void, E> values be combined correctly with intuitive syntax?
I am attempting to introduce std::expected into a code base that has many functions that return a bool indicating whether the function was successful (e.g. orig_check1 and orig_check2).  These functions are frequently invoked by higher level functions that also return a bool (e.g. orig_check).
Specifically, I would like to introduce error codes for all functions.  I believe std::expected<void, std::string_view> is a natural choice.
The following program contains 3 different approaches in the check function to combine the results of the lower-level functions (check1 and check2).
#include <cassert>
#include <expected>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

bool orig_check1(int val) { return val % 2 == 1; }
bool orig_check2(int val, int threshold) { return val <= threshold; }
bool orig_check(int val) { return orig_check1(val) && orig_check2(val, 100); }

////////////////////

std::expected<void, std::string_view> check1(int val)
{
    if (val % 2 == 0) {
        return std::unexpected{"even"};
    }
    return {};
}

std::expected<void, std::string_view> check2(int val, int threshold)
{
    if (val > threshold) {
        return std::unexpected{"too big"};
    }
    return {};
}

template <typename E>
std::expected<void, E> operator&&(std::expected<void, E> lhs, std::expected<void, E> rhs)
{
    return !lhs ? lhs : rhs;
}

std::expected<void, std::string_view> check(int val)
{
    // too verbose
    auto ret1 = [&]() -> std::expected<void, std::string_view> {
        if (auto ret = check1(val); !ret) {
            return ret;
        }
        if (auto ret = check2(val, 100); !ret) {
            return ret;
        }
        return {};
    }();

    // too complex
    std::expected ret2 = check1(val).and_then(std::bind_front(check2, val, 100));
    
    // incorrect due to lack of short-circuit evaluation
    std::expected ret3 = check1(val) && check2(val, 100);
    
    // sanity checking functional equivalence
    assert(ret1 == ret2 && ret1 == ret3);
    return ret1;
}

int main()
{
    check(0);
    check(1);
    check(123);
    return 0;
}

I'm not thrilled about any of these approaches.  #1 is too verbose.  #2 is too complex.  #3 is incorrect.  Ideally, I would be able to write the syntax of #3 with short-circuit evaluation.  Is this possible?  If not, is there a different approach that should be considered?

Why would you want to use std::expected for a predicate style function that doesn't fail?

@Eljay, the example code seems self-explanatory.  I want to pass an error string up the call chain.  In the real code base, there are 5 levels and about 20 functions in total.  Exceptions are not an option.  I am open to something other than std::expected.  It seemed like a suitable replacement for functions that currently return bool.

Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/78734779/11638718

A macro seems to work: #define AND(LHS, RHS) [&]{ auto lhs = LHS; return !lhs ? lhs : RHS; }() :-/ I was uncertain about the capturing lambda wrapped in the macro but it seems the capturing doesn't prevent the short-circuiting of the evaluation in the lambda body. I'm not sure whether this is reliable or just a side-effect of some inlining due to optimization...

...but even nesting is possible: demo on coliru. ;-)

First, just to have said it:
If your unexpected result paths are truly unexpected (or dare I even say exceptional), you could consider just using exceptions.
With that out of the way, I actually had a quite similar situation recently and considered two other approaches from the ones you tried.

Lazy Evaluation

This is a similar idea to @Caleth's answer, but uses lambdas to avoid the overhead of std::function: To get the short-circuiting behavior, we need to delay the actual invocation of check2 until we are sure that check1 succeeded. This can be done by wrapping the call to check2 in a lambda:
[&]() -> decltype(auto) { return check2(val, 100); }

and since writing that lambda every time can be quite annoying and error prone, you could hide it in a macro (and even add on correct noexcept propagation as a bonus):
#define LAZY(...)                                                    \
    [&]() noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { \
        return __VA_ARGS__;                                          \
    }

This lambda is then some invocable type that yieds a std::expected. We can use that to define the && operator as follows:
template <typename E, typename Lazy>
    requires std::is_invocable_r_v<std::expected<void, E>, Lazy>
std::expected<void, E> operator&&(std::expected<void, E> lhs, Lazy&& rhs)
{
    return !lhs ? lhs : std::forward<Lazy>(rhs)();
}

Your check method could then look as follows:
std::expected<void, std::string_view> check(int val) {
    return check1(val) && LAZY(check2(val, 100));
}

here is a working example on godbolt.

Coroutines

I tried (ab)using co-routines to make expecteds awaitable and short-circuit in case they are in the unexpected state. Your check method could then look like this:
Expected<void, std::string_view> check(int val)
{
    co_await cehck1(val);
    co_await check2(val, 100);
    
    co_return {};
}

This would have the desired short-circuiting behavior and, while a little unusual at first, is quite straight forward once you have seen it a few times.
There are a few caveats however:

notice that the above return type was Expected instead of std::expected. This is because you have to specialize std::coroutine_traits for the return type and specializing types in std is only allowed when using at least one custom type.
AFAIK there are no readily available libraries for this, so you would have to implement and maintain it yourself. And from my few dabbles in coroutines, the underlying machinery is quite difficult to get completely right.
Coroutines have a non-negligible overhead (the coroutine frame, heap allocations for said frame, etc...). Especially the heap allocations are what stopped me personally from using this approach. (While compilers are allowed to elide the heap allocation, at the time of writing this only clang is able to do it somewhat reliably).

If all that doesn't deter you, here is the godbolt playground I used to test this. It is by no means a complete implementation (no error checks, constraints, etc...), but could give you a good starting point.

Rather than the macro LAZY, you can use std::bind, which doesn't have the overhead of std::function

For this example sure, but std::bind only delays the evaluation of the function, the arguments to the function are still immediately evaluated.  With the LAZY macro the whole expression is only evaluated if needed, behaving more like traditional short-circuiting. i.e. check1(val) && std::bind(check2, val, calculate_upper_bound(val)) would still call calculate_upper_bound even if check1 fails.

You need to delay calling your checker functions.
template <typename E>
class expected_thunk {
    mutable std::optional<std::expected<void, E>> result;
    std::function<std::expected<void, E>()> thunk;
    void check() const {
        if (!result) {
            result.emplace(thunk());
        }
    }
public:
    expected_thunk(std::expected<void, E> result = {}) : result(std::move(result)) {}
    template <typename... Args, std::invocable<Args...> Fn>
    requires std::is_invocable_r_v<std::expected<void, E>, Fn, Args...>
    expected_thunk(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) : thunk(std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}

    operator std::expected<void, E>&() {
        check();
        return *result;
    }
    operator const std::expected<void, E>&() const {
        check();
        return *result;
    }
    operator bool() const {
        check();
        return *result;
    }
    bool operator!() const {
        check();
        return !*result;
    }
    std::expected<void, E>* operator->() {
        check();
        return &*result;
    }
    friend expected_thunk operator&&(expected_thunk lhs, expected_thunk rhs) {
        return { [lhs, rhs](){ return !lhs ? lhs : rhs; } };
    }
};

Which you can then use like this
using thunk_t = expected_thunk<std::string_view>;
thunk_t check(int val)
{
    return thunk_t{ check1, val } && thunk_t{ check2, val, 100 };
}

Coliru link

#include <cassert>
#include <expected>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

bool orig_check1(int val) { return val % 2 == 1; }
bool orig_check2(int val, int threshold) { return val <= threshold; }
bool orig_check(int val) { return orig_check1(val) && orig_check2(val, 100); }

std::expected<void, std::string_view> check1(int val)
{
    if (val % 2 == 0) {
        return std::unexpected{"even"};
    }
    return {};
}

std::expected<void, std::string_view> check2(int val, int threshold)
{
    if (val > threshold) {
        return std::unexpected{"too big"};
    }
    return {};
}

template <typename E>
std::expected<void, E> short_circuit_and(std::expected<void, E> lhs, std::expected<void, E> rhs)
{
    return !lhs ? lhs : rhs;
}

std::expected<void, std::string_view> check(int val)
{
    return short_circuit_and(check1(val), check2(val, 100));
}

int main()
{
    auto result1 = check(0);
    auto result2 = check(1);
    auto result3 = check(123);

    std::cout << "Check 0: " << (result1 ? "Success" : result1.error()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Check 1: " << (result2 ? "Success" : result2.error()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Check 123: " << (result3 ? "Success" : result3.error()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}

short_circuit_and: This function takes two std::expected objects and returns the first one if it contains an error. Otherwise, it returns the second one.
check: This function uses short_circuit_and to combine the results of check1 and check2, ensuring short-circuit evaluation.
This approach provides a clean and concise way to achieve the desired behavior with short-circuit evaluation.

Your function short_circuit_and() fails the expectation of OP for the same reason like OP's operator&&(): Before a function is called, all of its arguments are evaluated. Hence it's not short-circuit. Unfortunately, this is true for overloaded operators as well (the obstacle OP was stumbling over AFAIU).
